# Touch screen on a ASUS Q302L

Tags: screen, asus, touchscreen

I´m quite new to Linux and to Ubuntu. A week ago i decided to give it a shot and to be honest i really like the Ubuntu OS.

Out of the box is worked quite nice but there is one thing which I can´t get to work, the touchscreen.

I have a ASUS Q302l which was at the time a Best buy exclusive. I can´t find a lot for this laptop on the internet and i have spend hours now searching for a solution but didn't succeed yet.

I'm new to the command line rule but this is what I already tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
lsusb 
xinput

priyesh@priyesh-Q302LA:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

priyesh@priyesh-Q302LA:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FocalTechPS/2 FocalTech Touchpad          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]

priyesh@priyesh-Q302LA:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

priyesh@priyesh-Q302LA:~$ lshw
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
priyesh-q302la              
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smp vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 7860MiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 1716MHz
          capacity: 2700MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts flush_l1d cpufreq
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0b
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=hsw_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:42 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:46 memory:f7d1c000-f7d1ffff
        *-generic
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7d10000-f7d17fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series USB xHCI HC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:40 memory:f7d00000-f7d0ffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 8 Series HECI #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:43 memory:f7d24000-f7d2401f
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: 8 Series HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:45 memory:f7d18000-f7d1bfff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:19 memory:f7c00000-f7cfffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 7260
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
                version: cb
                serial: 80:86:f2:c7:6a:0a
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-42-generic firmware=17.948900127.0 ip=192.168.178.22 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:44 memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 8 Series LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:41 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7d22000-f7d227ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 8 Series SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f7d21000-f7d210ff ioport:f040(size=32)
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

but this returns only the two USB ports. 
The other commands returned input but didn't know how to recognize my touchscreen?

Your help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: I know this is four years after the original question was posted, but I have the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04. Hopefully, the solution(s) that could be applicable to this issue aren't obsolete.